# CLocationManager - how to trigger kCLErrorNetwork

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to handle all of the different error states of CLLocationManager, and I need to know how to trigger the error:

```
kCLErrorNetwork
```

The docs state:

```
kCLErrorNetwork - The network was unavailable or a network error occurred.
```

I figured I could trigger this by turning Airplane mode on, but that just gives me:

```
kCLErrorLocationUnknown - The location manager was unable to obtain a location value right now.
```

Anybody know how to trigger kCLErrorNetwork?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Working in the simulator I had some issues receiving locations when I had location services turned off in OS X, but I am pretty sure there was no error reporting.

You could always get a led box or use some other method to physically block the reception of all signals. Or come to my flat it has a similar effect.

Comment: So are you suggesting since the iPhone knows it's in Airplane mode, that it won't issue a kCLErrorNetwork error, but if it truly can't find a signal because of user's location, it will? If that's so, that'll make it difficult to test.

Comment: Will it? Can't you just turn off wifi and remove the sim card?